# Merging columns and jsonb object array into a single jsonb column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `visitors(id, email, first_seen, sessions, etc.)`

and another table `trackings(id, visitor_id, field, value)`  that stores custom, user supplied data.

I want to query these and merge the visitor data columns and the trackings into a single column called `data`

For example, say I have two trackings

```
(id: 3, visitor_id: 1, field: "orders_made", value: 2)
(id: 4, visitor_id: 1, field: "city", value: 'new york')
```

and a visitor

```
(id: 1, email: 'hello@gmail.com, sessions: 5)
```

I want the result to be on the form of

```
(id: 1, data: {email: 'hello@gmail.com', sessions: 5, orders_made: 2, city: 'new york'})
```

What's the best way to accomplish this using Postgres 9.4?

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying trackings is a bad idea. If you don't have many things to track, just store json instead; that's what it's made for. If you have a lot of things to track, you'll become very unhappy with the performance of trackings over time.

First you need a json object from trackings:

```
-- WARNING: Behavior of this with duplicate field names is undefined!
SELECT json_object(array_agg(field), array_agg(value)) FROM trackings WHERE ...
```

Getting json for visitors is relatively easy:

```
SELECT row_to_json(email, sessions) FROM visitors WHERE ...;
```

I recommend you do not just squash all those together. What happens if you have a field called email? Instead:

```
SELECT row_to_json((SELECT 
  (
SELECT row_to_json(email, sessions) FROM visitors WHERE ...
  ) AS visitor
  , (
SELECT json_object(array_agg(field), array_agg(value)) FROM trackings WHERE ...
  ) AS trackings
));
```

Comment: Hi, why exactly is this way of storing the trackings bad? I thought this way how you'd normally accomplish this in a relational context